# Create an image from a variable of the image's src

Tags: jquery

The variable imageOne is a correct path to an image. Why does the following not create an image with that path?

```
    jQuery('#main-img-cont').prepend('<img src="'imageOne'" />');
```

Comment: imageOne is a variable????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use

```
 jQuery('#main-img-cont').prepend("<img src='"+imageOne+"' />");
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing your string concatenation:

```
jQuery('#main-img-cont').prepend('<img src="' + imageOne + '" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error. Use

```
jQuery('#main-img-cont').prepend('<img src="'+imageOne+'" />');
```

But this kind of errors should be detected without going to SO by [using the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console).